# Cloudfront loading old (css/js) files after rails deployment with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Amazon's Cloudfront CDN along with Rails for our app and I'm now encountering a strange issue that I can't track down.

We store css and js files in Cloudfront and use the RELEASE value from capistrano in order to 'version' the files. (Method used here: http://stdout.wooswiff.com/2011/01/no-fuss-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-for-your.html )

A typical path to a file is: http://assets1.ourhost.com/rel-20120117173438/assets/main.css

The '20120117173438' is our RELEASE value that Capistrano creates during the deployment.

On deploy that RELEASE value is changed and then Cloudfront comes back to our app servers to get the new file. I've got some rewrite stuff going on server-side to ignore the RELEASE value in the  path and serve up the currently existing file from the filesystem.

The issue is this: on every deploy those RELEASE values are being updated correctly, so the sources being used to fetch the css and js files *is* being updated correctly, however, Cloudfront is serving us an older version of the file, from the previous deploy.

The only way for the correct files to be sourced is for me to do a second deploy in order to change the RELEASE value yet again.

The browser is not cacheing the files, so it's something going on with Cloudfront.

Has anyone seen anything similar to this? I'd love some extra input on what to look for.

Thanks.

Comment: I *think* I have narrowed down the problem and it is related to the deploy process itself. We have multiple app servers and we pull them out from the load balancer, one at a time, during deploys. I believe what is happening is that as an updated machine goes back live, a client hits it which results in a call to Cloudfront using the new release path. Cloudfront goes back to the origin server but gets one that is not yet updated and that is polluting the cache in Cloudfront. It seems I'm going to need to alter the deploys.

Comment: Have you looked at the asset pipeline? By having versions that are tied to the content you're guaranteed not to have that cache pollution problem

Comment: We are on Rails 3.0 so the asset pipeline is not quite what it is in 3.1 and above. Is there something specific to 3.0 that might be useful in this situation? Thanks.